# Extend coupon code action to present a popup when certian coupon codes are entered

Tags: coupon, coupon-codes, extend

I have read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267425/how-to-override-cart-controller-coupon-action-in-our-custom-module-magento

My question is how do I start writing this out.  I simply want to declare an if statment determining if a certain coupon code was entered.  and then if true then proceed with the normal actions but also present a popup or div block on the cart page.

I assume this would be best done through a module instead of the coupon.phtml template file?

Thank you

Comment: Have you found out, how to do it. i have been hitting the question for the past one month.

Comment: Have not figured it out =\